# How to post an array from AngularJS to SpringMVC Controller?

Tags: java, angularjs, arrays, list, http-post

I'm trying to post an array to spring mvc controller but I'm getting bad request. I'm specifically having issues with the array which I haven't done so far. I don't really know whether it is a problem with the jackson library or not. Any advises will be greatly welcome!

**Angular Serivce**

```
app.service('ConfirmacaoService', function ($http, $localStorage) {

    var usuario = $localStorage.usuarioLogado;
    var adicionadosNoCarrinho = $localStorage.confirmacaoCarrinho;

    this.salvarPedido = function (pedido) {

       var pedidoItem = {
            usuario: {idUsuario: usuario.idUsuario},
            pedido: {idPedido: 0},
            jogo: adicionadosNoCarrinho, ///THIS IS THE ARRAY
            endereco: {idEndereco: 0},
           // jogo: {idJogo: 0},
            frete: pedido.frete,
            totalPreco: pedido.totalPreco,
            precoFinal: pedido.precoFinal
        };

        var $res = $http.post('salvarPedido', pedidoItem);
        $res.success(function (data) {
            alert('deu cero', data);
        });
    };

});
```

**Spring MVC Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvarPedido", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
PedidoItems salvarPedido(@RequestBody PedidoItems pedidoItem) {

    dao.salvarItemPedido(pedidoItem);
    return pedidoItem;

}
```

**PedidoItems Model Class**

```
public class PedidoItems {

    private int idPedidoItem;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private Pedido pedido;
    private List<Jogo> jogo;
    private Endereco endereco;
    //private Pagamento pagamento;
    private double frete;
    private double totalPreco;
    private double precoFinal;

    public PedidoItems() {

        usuario = new Usuario();
        pedido = new Pedido();
        jogo = new ArrayList<>();

        endereco = new Endereco();
    }

    public List<Jogo> getJogo() {
        return jogo;
    }

    public void setJogo(List<Jogo> jogo) {
        this.jogo = jogo;
    }

    public int getIdPedidoItem() {
        return idPedidoItem;
    }

    public void setIdPedidoItem(int idPedidoItem) {
        this.idPedidoItem = idPedidoItem;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Pedido getPedido() {
        return pedido;
    }

    public void setPedido(Pedido pedido) {
        this.pedido = pedido;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public double getFrete() {
        return frete;
    }

    public void setFrete(double frete) {
        this.frete = frete;
    }

    public double getTotalPreco() {
        return totalPreco;
    }

    public void setTotalPreco(double totalPreco) {
        this.totalPreco = totalPreco;
    }

    public double getPrecoFinal() {
        return precoFinal;
    }

    public void setPrecoFinal(double precoFinal) {
        this.precoFinal = precoFinal;
    }
}
```

**Jogo Model Class**

```
public class Jogo {

    private int idJogo;
    private String nomeJogo;
    private double preco;
    private Console console;

    public Jogo(){
        console = new Console();
    }

    public int getIdJogo() {
        return idJogo;
    }

    public void setIdJogo(int idJogo) {
        this.idJogo = idJogo;
    }

    public String getNomeJogo() {
        return nomeJogo;
    }

    public void setNomeJogo(String nomeJogo) {
        this.nomeJogo = nomeJogo;
    }

    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    public Console getConsole() {
        return console;
    }

    public void setConsole(Console console) {
        this.console = console;
    }
}
```

The array looks like this: `jogo :Array(2)`

Comment: Are you trying to pass an array or just a JSON object? As per your code, it looks like you are trying to pass a JSON Object ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have proper content type of your request. it should be 'application/json'. Because Spring getting this info from request and choose proper message handler, in your case it should be Jackson lib. If content type of request is not 'application/json' you can specify it in `$http` params.

Example of `$http` header:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://your_url',
    data: serializedData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).success(...);
```